# Is there some swifty way to test if a variable is equal to some enum values ?

Tags: swift

Sample code :

```
enum myEnum {
  case foo, bar, baz
}
var myVar:myEnum = .foo


if myVar == .foo || myVar == .bar {

}
```

I was wondering if there was simplier was to write the if condition without a switch (In case I need to chain with other conditions)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is succinct code and readability and you aren't concerned about potential efficiency issues / future scope for tweaking then you can:

```
if [ .foo, .bar ].contains(myVar) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains` if you have a lot of cases to compare to:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case Foo, Bar, Baz, Qux   // and many more

    func isAmong(conditions: [MyEnum]) -> Bool {
        return conditions.contains(self)
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
if myVar.isAmong([.Foo, .Bar]) {
    // ok
}
```